# webView not loading game android 4.4.2 only in lollipop and mashmallow

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

[webView not loading game android 4.4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6nKs.jpg)

Hello friends, I've been fighting with this for several days maybe someone has an idea of how to solve it, my issue is that I am trying to load a game from an external source embeded inside a webView in `android 4.4.2 (kitkat)` i've been testing the code with other url's that run `javascript` and they load ok, it works also in `lollipop` and `masrshmallow` android versions but i can't make it load in 4.4.2v, my other issue is that I can't upgrade the tablet to a 5.0 version, so i'm stuck in Kitkat and need to make it work.

This is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView browser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Definimos el webView
    browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebBrowser);
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    browser.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    browser.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    browser.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    // Cargamos la web
    browser.loadUrl("http://game-portal.gameloft.com/2093/v4.0/?_rp_=/mig/browser/vi794dem1467865221402/review");
}
}
```

Error in android studio

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(32)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object http://interstatic06.gameloft.com has no method 'endsWith'", source: http://game-portal.gameloft.com/2093/v4.0/?_rp_=/mig/browser/vi794dem1467865221402/review (32)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I am very lost with this.

Any suggestion will be very well appreciated

Comment: (use a block quote (introduce each line using `> `) for the error message)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will next time sorry for my mistake